# Unable To Convert jpg/jpeg Images to Base64 in Cordova 4.0 ios

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, html5-canvas

I'm working on a cordova 4.0.0 ios project that involves conversion of images from the phone gallery to Base64 images and uploading them to a server.

I'm using the html5 canvas method to get the base64 data as follows:

```
   var img = new Image();
   img.src = URL;
   img.onload = function () {
   var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
   canvas.width = this.width;
   canvas.height = this.height;         
   var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
   ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
   var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg",0.5);
   alert("dataURL:" + dataURL);
```

The above code works fine for png images, but when I select a jpg image for conversion I get the output from the alert as follows:

"dataURL: data:"

Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using canvas.toDataURL(); directly which makes no conversion and gives PNG as output

```
var jpegUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"); //for JPEG output
var pngUrl = canvas.toDataURL(); // for PNG output
```

Comment: Hi, i've tried this method but it still doesn't return the required base64 data. sorry.